# Connect to local DB from Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jasper-reports, vpn

I've got an application server living in EC2 which I'd like to connect to a database on my local network. For reference the application server is a JasperReports Server instance from the AWS marketplace and the database is a MS SQL Server.

How can I get the app to talk to the db securely? I'd like to avoid attaching the MS SQL Server to a public facing IP if at all possible.

The db is at an AWS Direct Connect ready location. I'm not a networking guru though and it isn't clear to me if just enabling Direct Connect would be enough. Perhaps I'd also need to establish a VPC to VPN connection as outlined [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct Connect is a physical fiber connection to AWS, that would provide less latency and arguably more security to your connection, but that may not be necessary. You can connect to your private VPC subnet safely using a VPN as you mentioned, as the doc you mentioned, with either hardware or software gateways, but you'd need to test if the latency and throughput of the connection over the internet would be adequate for your solution.

Comment: Sorry for being dense but I gather this means that I'm correct in thinking Direct Connect alone would not put EC2 instances on the same networks as the local machines? I.e. Suppose I were going to setup Direct Connect anyway for the reasons you mention, I'd still require a VPC-->VPN connection to make the local network db available to an EC2 instance?

Comment: No, AWS Direct Connect (DX) is a physical connection. Although you can set up a VPN over DX, that is not required. From the FAQ:

Q. How does DX differ from an IPSec 
VPN?
A VPC VPN utilizes IPSec to establish connectivity between your intranet and Amazon VPC over the Internet. VPNs and are a good solution if you have an immediate need, have modest bandwidth requirements, and can tolerate variability in Internet connectivity. DX does not involve the Internet; it uses dedicated, private connections between your intranet and Amazon VPC.